# Linkedin API - UGCPost Video url is missing

Tags: linkedin-api, ugc

I am using following endpoint to fetch posts

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors[0]=urn:li:organization:XXXX&count=100&start=0

```
"media": [{
    "recipes": [
        "urn:li:digitalmediaProcessedAsset:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:XXXXXXXXXX,urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video-captions-thumbnails)"
    ],
    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:XXXXXXXXXX",
    "thumbnails": [],
    "status": "READY"
}]
```

I could see only digitalmedia Asset, But couldn't find original Url like sharable url like

https://dms.licdn.com/playback/C5105AQGCJKQiUe3pmw/8f26be64328644c090703fdc3afd05a8/feedshare-mp4_3300-captions-thumbnails/1507940147251-drlcss?e=1571133600&v=beta&t=RgRX9RM_Z50wt4cwqEHQ79vY6NU-KNcKVPFbEIftqAc

Note : For image, we are getting original Url

https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5122AQHvWYVXpP2Few/feedshare-shrink_1280/0?e=1573689600&v=beta&t=gLeLjTO5OlyF-F0RESk9YdSyqMggXLNmkWSUOqldFXw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using projection helped to solve this issue

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors[0]=urn:li:organization:XXXXX&count=100&projection=(paging,elements*(name,localizedName,vanityName,created(actor~(localizedFirstName, localizedLastName)),lastModified(actor~(localizedFirstName, localizedLastName)),specificContent(com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent(shareMediaCategory,shareCommentary,media(*(media~:playableStreams,originalUrl,description,title))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Projection parameter working as of Feb 2020

```
(paging,elements*(id,created,lastModified,author,specificContent(com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent(shareMediaCategory,shareCommentary,media(*(media~:playableStreams,originalUrl,description,title))))))
```