# Retrieve thumbnails for Linkedin Video Post (ugcPost API)

Tags: linkedin-api, thumbnails, ugc

I try to retrieve a thumbnails for a Video Post with the ugcPost api without any success.

I retrieve always an empty array for thumbnails.

Regarding the doc [Retrieve UGC Posts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#retrieve-ugc-posts), like the sample [response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#sample-response-1):

```
"com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
    "media": [
        {
            "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:123ABDEFHAG",
            "status": "READY",
            "thumbnails": []
        }
    ],
```

Any idea about how to retrieve a thumbnails with some projection or using the `digitalmediaAsset`  urn?

EDIT: I've already tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58401470/2270041 without any success

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#retrieve-ugc-posts) is not possible, simply stating

> Video thumbnails are not retrievable.