# No thumbnail for linkedin video using the ugcPosts API

Tags: linkedin-api

I tried to retrieve a video post thumbnail using the ugcPosts API, but `media.thumbnails` array is empty:

```
"media": [
 {
   "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:xxxx",
   "thumbnails": [],
   "status": "READY"
 }
]
```

Is there any way to retrieve a video thumbnail besides this API?

Already tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58401470/2270041

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, video thumbnail is not retrievable at the movement using APIs that are externalized as mentioned in below document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api

> thumbnails:   The thumbnails saved from the ingestion of this article. Video thumbnails are not retrievable.